# Why the data binding complete event is not being raised properly?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In Windows Forms I'm using a Data Grid View to display some data. The point is that the data is only loaded once the user picks a month from a datepicker.

Once the data is loaded, though, some work has to be done. In that case I've implemented the following:

```
private void LoadGrid()
{
    SourceTable.DataSource = _appService.LoadGridData(datePicker.Value);

    Grid.DataBindingComplete += (sender, args) => {
        MessageBox.Show('Work to be done');
    }
}

private void ClickSearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadGrid();
}
```

The method `LoadGridData` just uses a repository and return one `IList` with the data.

Now, with that, when I click the button the data does get loaded, but the `DataBindingComplete` method is not called, since the message box is not shown.

If I click again the button, the message box appears twice, that is, the method gets called twice. If I click it again, the message box appears four times.

There's something quite wrong here. So what am I doing wrong and how do I fix it so that the method gets called every time the data is loaded and only once?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the

```
Grid.DataBindingComplete += (sender, args) => {
    MessageBox.Show('Work to be done');
}
```

before you set the DataSource.

You might also want to consider either deregistering the handler afterwards, or putting the registration of the event in a better place like on the form load event, because at the moment, it will add a new lambda every time you click the Search button.

Comment: correct, sole reason event was not firing cause subscriber for `DataBindingComplete` was null but on second click that's not the case.

Comment: Instead of removing and adding it again, it's better to put the registration code in constructor after `InitializeComponent` or manually attach event handler using designer using events tab of property grid.